# function load doesn't grab / catch data to the included file

Tags: php, function, include, load

Let's say i have this function in my index php file

```
  function load($file){
    $file_path = $file.".php";
    if(file_exists($file_path)){
      include $file_path;
    }else{
      echo "no such file";
    }
}
```

and have those to in my index

```
$test = "test";


$test =load("test");
```

in my test php file

i try to echo test variable it tells me that it is undefiend variable

but if i just included my file as like this

include "test.php";

it prints my test variable with no problem

Any idea why this happens and what is the solution for it ?

Comment: Incluide is already doing the file_exists check and will issue ERROR_WARNING if the file does not exist. What's the use case for wrapping it in another (and slowing things down) function?

Comment: Your code worked fine for me. Are you trying to use this or any other files outside the working folder?

Comment: Try removing `$test = "test";` it's not needed. @HasanZohdy

Comment: guys this is just an example , i'm working on prject and i need to use this function in my controller files , so i just simplified my issue in this example because it has the same error in my project

Comment: So show us your controller files structure. Your question is unclear.

Comment: It's almost the same because i just started my projects some hours ago and i got this issue now 

but instead of $test , i user an array for my data to use it in another file 

something like this 

   function checkData(){
     $data = $this->data;
     print_r($this->load("model/login"));
   }

my model login 
class Login extends Model{

    private $data;
     function __construct($data){
       $this->data = $data;
       parent:: __construct();
       $this->checkLogin();
     }
  function checkLogin(){
    print_r($this->data);
  }

}

$login = new Login($data);

Comment: Then, why didn't you post that in the first place?

Comment: Because as i said , it is the same problem and i just wrote it in small example

Answer (score 2):

The variable from the included file remain in the scope of the function load. It won't be accessible directly from your parent / main scope.

You need, in order to access variables defined in the included file, directly include the file in the scope where you want to access these.

So, you need to remove that function call to `load()` and call `include` directly to solve your problem. There's no way around. (except maybe `get_defined_vars()` and `extract()` (**not recommended!**))

Comment: I know this , is there is anyway to include my files from load function ?

Comment: _(except maybe `get_defined_vars()` and `extract()` (__not recommended!__))_ — read about them in the documentation, then you'll probably know what to do.

Comment: No , i'm not talking about variables , i'm talking about making function like mine but working with no problems !

Comment: @HasanZohdy please explain more clearly what you mean?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with OP's code. OP is most likely trying to access files from outside the working folder. I tested OP's code as is with files inside the same folder.

Comment: I need to deal with this "load" function becuase i'm gonna use it in my project , so what is the best solution to make it works althought it is alomst just including a file , no more .. no less !!

Comment: @Fred-ii- he's talking about undefined variable. His description is a bit confusing, so tried to guess the best I could.

Comment: I agree. I think it's a scope issue or path issue. @bwoebi  is now talking about controller files.

Comment: All what i need to make my function just work isntead of including my file with include , i'm including it via a function 

so it would be in my controller 

$this->load("filename);

Comment: yes, then `return get_defined_vars();` in your load() function and use `extract(load($filename));` when calling it.

Comment: Actually , i don't know what does get_defiend_vars() do exactly

but still nobody answered me ... why my function doesn't work ?

I mean i need logical reasons

Comment: Read my answer. The scope is different. If you don't know what a scope it, google it.

Comment: You can't use `$this->load("filename);` since it needs to be set inside a class and not just a function. @HasanZohdy

Comment: Iknow Fred It is already in a class 

i just removed $this->load and used include 

my code worked with no problems 

so i knew the problem is in my load function

Comment: I suggest then that you place your controller code in your question instead of in the comments area. It's going to be more legible in your question's body, rather than in the comments box. @HasanZohdy

Comment: @HasanZohdy You got it. Just look above. It's there, you maybe just don't understand it, but then learn to understand it.

Comment: @Fred , i don't care about my controller file 

i'm just trying to make a fonction for loading files  no more no less

Comment: @Bwoebi my problem is not in variables here 

my problem is my load function :)

Comment: @HasanZohdy Last ditch effort: Try making `$test` global but that's not good practice. Plus you do realize that you don't need `$test = "test";` just keep `$test =load("test");` which is what I did.

Comment: I guess i just did something wrong 

$test is just a variable that i want to be printed in my test page 

, I mean it is not related to my page name or my function 

Just deal with it as for example like $hello = "hello";

then what i want to do is just printing hello variable in my included file :)

Comment: similar thing, then you just need to do the inverse with get_defined_vars as parameter and extract in function?

Comment: @HasanZohdy When using `$test =load("test");` this calls up a file with the name `test.php` which in a file I created with the same name has an echo in there. Same thing. You may be overthinking this. Using `$test =load("test2");` loads a page called `test2.php` etc.

Comment: @Fred,@bowebi, guys thanks for your mass help but as i see we are running in a closed circle with no results .

my question was exactlly i have some variables and loader function to load files and i just want to use these variables/arrays/etc in my included files . And unfortunately i'm not really understanding both of you well :)

Comment: @HasanZohdy then first learn more about PHP and then come back to that code. (please accept the answer though)

Comment: @bwoebi well , i know more about php but you didn't answer my question as i said , if you read my question i just asked what is the problem of my function and how to solve it . You told me to include my file directly >>> i guess you know that i can do it but you gave me an answer which i don't need !!!